# Boolean loop wont set false

Tags: java, loops, boolean

i have loops in all my other applications, but this just wont seem to work.

```
public void loanBook() {
    boolean loop3 = true;
    System.out.println("So you wanna loan a book? Excellent choice.");
        while (loop3) {
            for (int i=0; i<books.size(); i++) {

                System.out.println("Search for the book you're looking for: ");
                String book = in.nextLine();

                if (books.get(i).toString().contains(book) == true) {
                    System.out.println("Looking for: " + books.get(i).toString() + "?");
                    System.out.println("press y to loan book or n to try again");
                    String choice1 = in.next();
                    if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                        for (int j=0; j<customers.size(); j++) {
                            if (customers.get(j).getSignedIn() == true) {
                                customers.get(j).booksLoaned.add(books.get(i)); 
                                Timer.delayFunction();
                                System.out.println(customers.get(j).printBookList()); 
                                System.out.println("Returning to main menu");
                         ---->   loop3 = false;  doesnt work for some reason       
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
        System.out.println("Couldnt find book");
        }
    }
```

It keeps repeating the loop3 even though i set it to false. It should go back to the main menu afterwards, but it wont.

I tried to isolate the problem, and no problem. I've been looking at the code for an hour now and i cant seem to find any problem. Anybody got a clue?

the isolated problem that worked:

```
public void loanBook() {
    boolean loop = true;
    while (loop) {
        System.out.println("lol");
 ----->   loop = false;   works fine
    }
    System.out.println("lol");
}
```

my System out prints work just fine so i know it gets through my loops correctly.

Comment: you set it to false, that is true, but you also have to wait until you got through both for loops until you end the while loop. once you set it to false you might want to `break;` the for loops

Comment: is there an easier way to get to the index of the customer than a for loop? so many loops for just one add method..

Comment: you could pass the current customer as parameter to the method

Comment: Why don't you just write `return;` to exit the method at that point?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer how would i get the exact customer without an index?

Comment: if i make my loanBook method take a parameter (Customer customer) i would have to find that costumer when i call the method, is that even possible?

Comment: @GustavBangNielsen its all dependent on how your program overall works. somewhere you have to set the customer to signedIn and there you could know which one is signed in

Comment: yeah, i do that in my login. This method is called way before in the login section. I don't see how i get it from there and to the parameter :/
Sorry if i make you explain to the last little detailed, it's just that i make a for loop and if loop every time i change a tiny thing on a customer in this case, and it would make my day alot easier if that could be avoided :P

Comment: ah sorry, i can just call the method with the needed parameter, sorry that was a dumb question. Thnx for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 nested loops. The other loop (the while loop) terminates when `loop3` becomes `false`.

However, you are setting `loop3` to `false` deep within the inner most loop, which means the `while` loop won't check the value of `loop3` until the 2 inner for loops finish.

If you want to break from all the loops, you'll need some break statements and or additional conditions. For example:

```
    while (loop3) {
        for (int i=0; i<books.size() && loop3; i++) {

            System.out.println("Search for the book you're looking for: ");
            String book = in.nextLine();

            if (books.get(i).toString().contains(book)) {
                System.out.println("Looking for: " + books.get(i).toString() + "?");
                System.out.println("press y to loan book or n to try again");
                String choice1 = in.next();
                if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                    for (int j=0; j<customers.size() && loop3; j++) {
                        if (customers.get(j).getSignedIn()) {
                            customers.get(j).booksLoaned.add(books.get(i)); 
                            Timer.delayFunction();
                            System.out.println(customers.get(j).printBookList()); 
                            System.out.println("Returning to main menu");
                            loop3 = false;    
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        System.out.println("Couldnt find book");
    }
```

This will leave both inner loops when `loop3` becomes false, which will allow the outer loop to terminate immediately.

Comment: It keeps saying, looking for "book"? for all my books, when it really should only find the one that contains the scanned input from the user. Can it be that my contain method is wrong and therefore it goes in my 
if (books.get(i).toString().contains(book) == true)  even though it only should once?

Comment: @GustavBangNielsen Did you notice the conditions I added to the for loops?

Comment: ah && loop3, genius. Let me try it out :)

Comment: it works like a charm! it hops out of my loops when i put a book into my bookarray. One thing still bugs though, it asks me if im looking for the index[0] book before i even type in my search.

Comment: @GustavBangNielsen I suggest changing `String choice1 = in.next();` to `String choice1 = in.nextLine();`

Comment: still buggy, i suspect that the scanner is eating one of my println, sometimes it does that..

Answer (score 0):

You want to break out of the while loop as soon as you set it to `false`. You could do that with labels

```
public void loanBook() {
    boolean loop3 = true;
    System.out.println("So you wanna loan a book? Excellent choice.");
        while (loop3) {
            outerloop: // added
            for (int i=0; i<books.size(); i++) {

            System.out.println("Search for the book you're looking for: ");
            String book = in.nextLine();

            if (books.get(i).toString().contains(book) == true) {
                System.out.println("Looking for: " + books.get(i).toString() + "?");
                System.out.println("press y to loan book or n to try again");
                String choice1 = in.next();
                if (choice1.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                    for (int j=0; j<customers.size(); j++) {
                        if (customers.get(j).getSignedIn() == true) {
                            customers.get(j).booksLoaned.add(books.get(i)); 
                            Timer.delayFunction();
                            System.out.println(customers.get(j).printBookList()); 
                            System.out.println("Returning to main menu");
                             loop3 = false;
                             break outerloop; // added     
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    System.out.println("Couldnt find book");
    }
}
```